# Mapping objects in objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I am trying to map and object in React and keep getting the following error
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

My Expected Outcome

task-1
task-2
task-3
task-4

Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class MapEx extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
      tasks: {
        'task-1': { id: 'task-1', content: 'clean house' },
        'task-2': { id: 'task-2', content: 'walk dog' },
        'task-3': { id: 'task-3', content: 'Do pushups' },
        'task-4': { id: 'task-4', content: 'have a drink' }
      }
  };
}
  render() {

    const tasks = this.state.tasks
    console.log(tasks)
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
       <p> {this.tasks.map((task) => 
              task.id)}</p>


      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MapEx;
```

Comment: `this.tasks` is undefined, you declared `const task` in the scope of render so just use `tasks.map` and as others have pointed out map is for arrays not objects so that also needs to be looked at

Comment: Map is an array method. You must first use `Object.values` to get what you want

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1. You reference `this.tasks` instead of `this.state.tasks`.
2. You are using `map` on an object instead of an array.

Try something like this:

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    {Object.values(this.state.tasks).map(task => <p>{task.id}</p>)}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` can only be used on arrays. To begin with, convert your data to array DS and proceed as below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MapEx extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
      tasks: {
        'task-1': { id: 'task-1', content: 'clean house' },
        'task-2': { id: 'task-2', content: 'walk dog' },
        'task-3': { id: 'task-3', content: 'Do pushups' },
        'task-4': { id: 'task-4', content: 'have a drink' }
      }
    };
  }
  render() {

    const tasks = this.state.tasks
    console.log(tasks)
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        {Object.values(tasks).map(task => (<p>{task.id}</p>))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MapEx;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

- Destructuring state
- As tasks is an object you can't map over it, you need to use object.keys

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class MapEx extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
      tasks: {
        'task-1': { id: 'task-1', content: 'clean house' },
        'task-2': { id: 'task-2', content: 'walk dog' },
        'task-3': { id: 'task-3', content: 'Do pushups' },
        'task-4': { id: 'task-4', content: 'have a drink' }
      }
    };
  }
  render() {

    const {tasks} = this.state
    console.log(tasks)
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My tasks</h1>
        {!!tasks ? Object.values(tasks).map(task => (<p>{task.id}</p>)) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MapEx;
```

Working example on https://codesandbox.io/s/react-boilerplate-r68kh

Comment: It's called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), not _deconstructing_.

Comment: You are right! English is not my first language and I have poorly translated it. I will update!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to read the docs of `map`.
It works with arrays and not objects.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score -1):

`tasks` is an object, you need to convert it into an array to make this work.

```
this.state =  {
      tasks: [
        { id: 'task-1', content: 'clean house' },
        { id: 'task-2', content: 'walk dog' },
        { id: 'task-3', content: 'Do pushups' },
        { id: 'task-4', content: 'have a drink' }
      ]
  };
```

Answer (score -2):

You can `map` over an array and here `tasks` is an object